# Make sheet orientation to full screen when exporting to PDF

Tags: laravel, file, pdf, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to get the orientation of sheet to fullscreen while exporting it to pdf. This is my code

```
        Excel::create('Benchmark Constituents', function($excel) use ($Array_data) {

            $excel->setTitle('Benchmark Constituents');                     
            $excel->setDescription('File containing Benchmark Constituents');

        $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($Array_data) {
            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');                                                            
            $sheet->mergeCells('E1:G1');
            $sheet->cell('E1', function($cell) {
                $cell->setValue('Benchmark Constituents');
                $cell->setAlignment('center');
                $cell->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                $cell->setBackground('##000000');
                $cell->setFont(array(
                    'family'     => 'Calibri',
                    'size'       => '16',
                    'bold'       =>  true
                    ));
            });                                                                                         
            $sheet->fromArray($Array_data, null,"A3",true);
            $sheet->row(3, function($row) {
                $row->setBackground('#808080');
                $row->setFontColor('#ffffff');
            });
            $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                $row->setBorder('none');
            });
            $sheet->row(2, function($row) {
                $row->setBorder('none');

            });
        });
    })->download('pdf');
```

I am getting this file as an output some of the table columns get hidden just because of the page width:

[image]

Comment: can anyone help on the issue plz

Answer (score 0):

Try to set page margin to 0

```
// Set all margins to 0
$sheet->setPageMargin(0);
```

[Document here](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export)